# JQuery Validator Method Check certain phrases

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I'm using the jquery validator plugin and I want to add a custom method that checks to see if the user inputted a certain keyword. If they didn't then they can't continue, kind of like a password. There are multiple keywords they could enter, they just need to enter one of them and they can move on. I also want to remove any whitespaces they might enter in. Here's what I have so far:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("code", function(value, element) { 
    return this.optional(element) || /^\bCODE1\b+\bCODE2\b+\bCODE3\b$/i.test(value);
    }, jQuery.format("Please enter a correct code"));
```

This isn't working like I want it to, how should I change it to make it work? Thanks

Comment: Your regex isn't working. What exactly do you want to allow?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker if the user enters CODE1 or CODE2 or CODE3 , then I want the validation to pass but ONLY if they enter in those codes. But the regex i have in my code is not doing that. It's like password checker, if you enter the correct password, then you're good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("code", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(CODE1)|(CODE2)|(CODE3)$/i.test(value);
}, jQuery.format("Please enter a correct code"));
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/shv7h/